# How to make string fast enumeration in string in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example i have usual fast enumeration

```
for (var myChar:Character) in "Hello World!"
{//code }
```

This works fine and i can do whatever i want with each character of this string.
But what if i want to use string instead of character, like this

```
for ( var myStr : String) in "Hello World!"//this is error
{
    switch myStr
    {
    case "Hello":
    //code
    case "World!":
    //code
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` to divide the string into an array of strings:

```
import Foundation // not necessary if you import UIKit or Cocoa

for myStr in "Hello World!".componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:" ")) {
    switch myStr {
    case "Hello":
        println("well hello there")
    case "World!":
        println("the whole world")
    default:
        println("something else")
    }
}
```

In place of `NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:" ")` can also use `NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()` or `NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndnewlineCharacterSet()` depending on what kinds of characters divide your words.

---

If your words are separated by a single space, you can use the shorter:

```
for myStr in "Hello World!".componentsSeparatedByString(" ") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did that work for you? If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer to turn it green.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just enumeratate by strings over a string. you need to tell what ranges the substring has to have.

Here it is done by words:

```
var str:String = "Hello World!"
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(Range<String.Index>(start:str.startIndex , end: str.endIndex), options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
    switch substring
    {
    case "Hello":
        println("Hi")
    case "World":
        println("universe")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

but actually I am cheating. In you code you want to switch for `World!`, but I am using `World`. I do this as in word-based enumeration non-alphanumeric characters are ignored.

But we have all information to fix it

```
var str:String = "Hello World!"
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(Range<String.Index>(start:str.startIndex , end: str.endIndex), options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in

    var enclosingStr = str.substringWithRange(enclosingRange)
    enclosingStr = enclosingStr.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    switch enclosingStr
    {
    case "Hello":
        println("Hi")
    case "World!":
        println("universe")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While in Swift 2.0, I use

```
let line = "Hello, world"
for (index, value) in line.characters.enumerate() {
  // do something
}
```